# Keras model.fit very, very slow compared to model.predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I am working on a binary image classification task with large inputs (10e8 features). I have a small convolutional network defined in Keras with a Tensorflow backend that can in principle classify a batch of 500 such images in under a second using model.predict. Training the model is very slow compared to this. Using model.fit on just a single image takes around 20 minutes for each epoch. Is this sort of disparity to be expected? Are there any simple improvements?

Python code to reproduce this is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Dropout,Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=[4,150], activation='relu',input_shape=(257,44101,1)))      
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 500)))
model.add(Flatten)
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())

ex_tensor=tf.ones([100,257,44101,1])
ex_labels=tf.ones([100,1])

model(ex_tensor) # Fast
model.fit(ex_tensor,ex_label,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=1) # Very slow
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your language. "10e8 features" are you saying the input size of the image is 10^9 pixels or are you doing something to generate "features" first? I think you'll need to include your full call to 'fit' and maybe some dummy numpy arrrays to represent the data.

Comment: Code added above.

Comment: That helps a lot! When you do model.fit, it does quite a few calculations. Especially with the adam optimizer on the **first epoch**. It has to do a forward pass, then it uses backpropagation and calculates the derivatives. I would expect it could take around 10 to 100 times longer than just doing a fit call. Did you measure the two calls, the fast one and the 'very slow' one?  Also, your fit call is happening on 100 such images.

Comment: Thanks, due to memory constraints I load in 500 images at a time so 100 is a bit less taxing as an example. The 'model(ex_tensor)' runs in 100ms, but the 'model.fit...' line takes around 1000 to 2000 seconds, even when I reduce the tensor size to have one in the first dimension. I was expecting that sort of disparity of around 100 times that you mentioned, but it seems to take more than 10,000 times longer to do the backprop here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is to be expected.

Predicting with a neural network is a simple matter of several matrix multiplications. Training/fitting your model, on the other hand, is a much more complex bit of math. You are waiting for the algorithm to figure out how to distinguish one picture from another - not an easy task.

You should never train on just one image. This will just cause the model to memorize that one image. Make sure you are training on a training set of your data and reserving the other (say 20%) for testing or validating the quality of your model.

Some ways to speed things up:

1. Decrease the number of features by scaling down your images. 1,000,000,000 features is A LOT of features.
2. Decrease the complexity of your model or change the hyperparameters.
3. If those aren't acceptable, use a more powerful computer.